# Numpy 3d array indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-indexing, array-broadcasting

I have a 3d numpy array (**n_samples x num_components x 2**) in the example below *n_samples* = 5 and *num_components* = 7.

I have another array (**indices**) which is the selected component for each sample which is of shape (*n_samples*,).

I want to select from the data array given the indices so that the resulting array is **n_samples x 2**.

The code is below:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(77)
data=np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 7, 2))
indices = np.array([0, 1, 6, 4, 5])
#how can I select indices from the data array?
```

For example for data 0, the selected component should be the 0th and for data 1 the selected component should be 1.

Note that I can't use any for loops because I'm using it in Theano and the solution should be solely based on numpy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
In [36]: data[np.arange(data.shape[0]),indices,:]
Out[36]: 
array([[7, 4],
       [7, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [8, 2],
       [5, 8]])
```

Comment: yeah, that's it. I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

To get component #0, use

```
data[:, 0]
```

i.e. we get every entry on axis 0 (samples), and only entry #0 on axis 1 (components), and implicitly everything on the remaining axes.

This can be easily generalized to

```
data[:, indices]
```

to select all relevant components.

---

But what OP really wants is just the diagonal of this array, i.e. `(data[0, indices[0]], (data[1, indices[1]]), ...)` The diagonal of a high-dimensional array can be extracted using the `diagonal` function:

```
>>> np.diagonal(data[:, indices])
array([[7, 7, 4, 8, 5],
       [4, 3, 5, 2, 8]])
```

(You may need to transpose the result.)

Comment: data[:, indices] results in shape (5, 5, 2) while I need a (5, 2) shape.

Comment: @Afshin `data[:, 0]` is `(5, 2)`, for a single component. What `(5, 2)` array you want when you have got five components?

Comment: for each sample (first dimension) we have 7 2d components. We know the indices of one of those 7 components for each sample. We want for each sample to select the corresponding 2d component. data[:, 0] is the correct one, but it is just returning the 0 component for all samples while it should return the 7th component (index 6) for the third sample.

Comment: `data[:,indices][np.arange(n_samples),np.arange(n_samples)]` works but is obtuse.

Comment: @Afshin What about `np.diagonal(data[:, indices]).T`

Comment: This, I think is the one I need though I thought there is a simple indexing for it. If you change the answer I'll be able to select it as answer.

Comment: both the above answers expand the matrix a lot and select the diagonal section, I should test which one is faster and also if there is a better solution that doesn't expand the matrix because in my case indices are the number of batch_size and can be big.

Comment: @Afshin Updated. I guess hpaulj's one is faster since it doesn't need to build the intermediate #Samples×#Indices×2 array.

Answer (score 2):

You have a variety of ways to do so, but this is my loop recommendation:

```
selection = np.array([ datum[indices[k]] for k,datum in enumerate(data)])
```

The resulting array, `selection`, has the desired shape.

Comment: I can't use for loops because I'm using Theano, need a solely numpy solution.

Comment: I think you should add that constraint to your original post.